# Restrict spring resources based on active profiles

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-profiles

I have restricted creation of beans, based on the spring active profiles. So that, these **cannot be accessible in Production environmen**t.

```
<beans profile="test">  
    <bean id="testSwaggerConfig" class="com.example.rest.config.SwaggerConfig" />
</beans>
```

Similarly, how can I **restrict resources based on the spring active profiles**. So that, while accessing to the html pages I should get **404**.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/rest/*.html" location="/rest-doc/" />
```

I am passing the active profile from environment variable `-Dspring.profiles.active` (May be this info useful for someone)

Answer (score 0):

You can define parameter bean for each profile like this

```
<bean name="profileParam" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="/rest/*.html" />
</bean>
```

And place desired mapping in the param
Then use the param from profile like this

```
<mvc:resources mapping="#{profileParam}" location="/rest-doc/" />
```

Thus for differen profiles you have different mapping accessible

Comment: Thank you for reply @stanislavL. I should remove the resource mapping for the prod environment. It should come only in dev/test environment. One more doubt by your answer is, we can't provide profile directly to bean. Making it to work, we should keep it in beans tag. Beans tag will not allow prior to resources tag.. Please correct me if I am wrong...